# How to make BlazeDS name conversion to work for properties beginning with a lower-case letter followed by an upper-case one?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds, amf

I have some trouble with the conversion applied by BlazeDS to the name of the properties when this name begins with a lower-case letter followed by a capital letter.

I have an ActionScript class similar to this:

```
package as.pkg {

    [RemoteClass(alias="java.pkg.Example")]
    public class Example {
        private var mXRatio:Number;

        public function get xRatio():Number {
            return mXRatio;
        }

        public function set xRatio(r:Number):void {
            mXRatio = r;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have the equivalent Java class on the server:

```
package java.pkg;

public class Example {
    private Double mXRatio;

    public Double getXRatio() {
        return mXRatio;
    }

    public void setXRatio( Double r ) {
        mXRatio = r;
    }
}
```

Sending instances from ActionScript to Java works perfectly fine. But when the instances are sent from Java to ActionScript, the following error is displayed:

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property XRatio on as.pkg.Example.

Why BlazeDS does not convert the X of XRatio there? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

BlazeDS uses reflection to inject values into your properties while serializing.

Therefore, your properties (public getter/setter pair or public variable) must have the exact same name or you will get serialization errors like the one you describe above.

Try this and it should be fine:

```
package as.pkg {

    [RemoteClass(alias="java.pkg.Example")]
    public class Example {
        private var mXRatio:Number;

        public function get XRatio():Number { //uppercase X i.s.o lowercase x
            return mXRatio;
        }

        public function set XRatio(r:Number):void { //uppercase X i.s.o lowercase x
            mXRatio = r;
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Actually it works well if I use `xratio` in ActionScript and `getXratio()` in Java, even if this is not the exact same name. BlazeDS deals well with properties starting with a lower-case letter in AS and an upper-case letter in Java, which is the classic naming convention, but not in the case described above.